Verifying transaction rollback in spring-boot integration test
I am trying to write an integration test that verifies database rows are rolled back if one of the operations in a transaction fails. However, though I see the rollback being triggered, my database changes are not actually rolled back.
I've opted to go with a PlatformTransactionManager approach to avoid all the magic of @Transaction (at least for now) so that I can see what's going on.
My service with the transactional method looks like:
@Service
public class ThingService {
    private final ThingDao thingDao;
    private final PlatformTransactionManager txManager;

    @Autowired
    public ThingService(final ThingDao dao, final PlatformTransactionManager txManager) {
        this.thingDao = dao;
        this.txManager = txManager;
    }

    public void createOrUpdate(final List<ThingRequest> requests) {

        final TransactionDefinition txDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        final TransactionStatus txStatus = txManager.getTransaction(txDef);

        try {
            requests.forEach(c -> thingDao.createThing(ThingModel.fromCreateRequest(c)));

            txManager.commit(txStatus);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            txManager.rollback(txStatus);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void createUpdateThings(final List<ThingRequest> requests) throws ControllerBadRequestException {
        try {
            createOrUpdate(requests);
        } catch (final Throwable t) {
            logger.error("A database exception occurred during createUpdateThings", t);
            throw new MyBadRequestException(t);
        }
    }
}

My test is set up so that 3 rows should be inserted and then the final insert should trigger a RuntimeException. In my test, I see that the rollback is supposed to have occurred (i.e., the assertThrows line passes, and I can debug and see that the txManager.rollback line is hit.  However, when I make calls to the database to verify the first 3 rows are rolled back, it seems they are not.
My TransactionManager appears to be correctly initialized (in that I can see it is not null and has the expected properties).
Here is the test code:
@MybatisTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class ThingServiceIntegrationTest extends AbstractPostgresJupiterTest {

    // NOTE: AbstractPostgresJupiterTest sets up a PostgreSQLContainer and initializes datasource properties
    // Works find for all other integration tests except this transactional test

    @Autowired
    private ThingMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager txManager;

    private ThingService service;

    private ThingDao dao;

    private @NotNull ThingService makeTestService() {
        class TestDao extends ThingDao {
            public TestDao(final ThingMapper thingMapper) {
                super(thingMapper);
            }

            @Override
            public UUID createThing(final ThingModel model) {
                if (Objects.equals(model.name(), "Bad Request")) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Database exception");
                }
                return super.createThing(model);
            }
        }

        final ThingDao daoWithFailure = new TestDao(mapper);
        return new ThingService(daoWithFailure, txManager);
    }

    @Test
    @Description("Should rollback on error")
    public void rollbackOnError() throws MyBadRequestException {
        final ThingService thingService = makeTestService();

        final List<ThingRequest> createRequests = Stream.of(1, 3)
                .map(i -> generateThingRequest())
                .toList();
        final ThingRequest badRequest = createRequests.getLast().withName("Bad Request");
        final List<ThingRequest> all = new ArrayList<>(createRequests);
        all.add(badRequest);

        assertThrows(MyBadRequestException.class, () -> thingService.createUpdateThings(all));

        // should rollback all inserts
        createRequests.forEach(req -> {
            // FAILS HERE
            assertTrue(dao.getByName(req.name()).isEmpty()); 
        });
    }
}

Why am I not seeing the actual rollback from the db perspective?
Thanks in advance!

Which database? Are you using tables / db that actually supports transacations (using MySQL with MyISAM tables for instance support no transactions).

@M.Deinum Postgres

What does your AbstractPostgresJupiterTest look like, what does your generateThingRequest do. What does your dao look like? Please add that to your question.

@Sydney The transaction is managed by TransactionalTestExecutionListener. You need to call TestTransaction.end() before checking the table content. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/testcontext-framework/tx.html

@ave I could have sworn I posted a thank-you weeks ago, but thank you.  That did it.

@Sydney Ya, I read it ️ They delete OK/thanks comments (as 'obsolete' if I have to guess) and it makes people look rude  Feel free to add an answer yourself if you have time.

Revisiting, this, I am now seeing that TestTransaction.end() effectively rolls back anything that was done in the test (as MybatisTest is @Transactional), so while my test is passing, I don't think it's actually reflecting a roll-back happening because of my application transaction.  If I put TestTransaction.end() inside a test where no exceptions happen, checking for the expected inserts also fails.

OK, I have figured out the problem.  Because I wanted to set up a mix of Mock and Autowired dependencies for my service, in order to mock an exception, I was manually instantiating my service (it is not marked as @Autowired).  Consequently, it was not being wired up to be proxied as is needed by @Transaction.

As mentioned above, in order for my service under test to be correctly wired up to be Proxied, it needs to be annotated in the test as @Autowired.
And, in order to make my service @Autowired while still being able to mock a failure, I needed to change my dependencies from being @Autowired to using @SpyBean.
In addition, @MybatisTest is itself @Transactional, so that masks whether the rollback in my application code is actually working.  So, I have fallen back to using @SpringBootTest.
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class ThingServiceIntegrationTest extends AbstractPostgresJupiterTest {
    // NOTE: AbstractPostgresJupiterTest sets up a PostgreSQLContainer and initializes datasource properties

    @SpyBean
    private ThingMapper mapper;

    @SpyBean
    private ThingDao dao;

    @Autowired
    private ThingService service;


    @Test
    @Description("Should rollback on error")
    public void rollbackOnError() {
        final List<ThingRequest> createRequests = Stream.of(1, 3)
                .map(i -> generateThingRequest())
                .toList();
        final ThingRequest badRequest = createRequests.getLast().withName("Bad Request");
        final List<ThingRequest> all =
                Stream.concat(createRequests.stream(), Stream.of(badRequest)).toList();

        doThrow(new MyBadRequestException("bad")).when(dao)
                .createThing(argThat(thing -> thing.id().equals(badCreate.id())));

        assertThrows(MyBadRequestException.class, () -> thingService.createUpdateThings(all));

        // should rollback all inserts
        createRequests.forEach(req -> {
            assertTrue(dao.getByName(req.name()).isEmpty()); 
        });
    }
}

Finally, one other tweak I had to do was due to MyService having an @Autowired constructor (vs autowired fields).  This seemed to cause problems for the @SpyBeans.  The fix for this was to mark the constructor parameters as @Lazy.
With all these changes, I was able to use @Transactional instead of the transaction manager approach.
@Service
public class ThingService {
    private final ThingDao thingDao;

    @Autowired
    public ThingService(@Lazy final ThingDao dao) {
        this.thingDao = dao;
        this.txManager = txManager;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
    public void createOrUpdate(final List<ThingRequest> requests) {
        requests.forEach(c -> thingDao.createThing(ThingModel.fromCreateRequest(c)));
    }

    public void createUpdateThings(final List<ThingRequest> requests) throws ControllerBadRequestException {
        try {
            createOrUpdate(requests);
        } catch (final Throwable t) {
            logger.error("A database exception occurred during createUpdateThings", t);
            throw new MyBadRequestException(t);
        }
    }
}

Hope this is helpful for someone else.
